# How convert Merchant Order Number to Google Order Number?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-pay

My company has an Android application with integrated In-app billing.  When customer purchases an order, the application recieves the order id.  After that, the app sends this data to the server, and the server checks this order id for existence, via Notification History API.

Before November 9, this order id always was a format known as Google Order Number (for example 56260349814XXXX).  After November 9, we began recieving order ids as a format known as Merchant Order Number (for example 1299976316905470XXXX.137189007792XXXX).

How can our sever check orders by Merchant Order Number?
Or, how can we convert Merchant Order Number to Google Order Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a "mixed" account - an account that handles both "legacy" and newer Wallet APIs?

AFAIK, `Notification History API` is still a "legacy" Google Checkout API - even it *does* work for newer APIs. So if for example you do a `notification-history-request` by time period, you *will* get orders from "all" of them (at least it does for me in my "mixed" sandbox account):

- A "legacy" Google Checkout order only has `google-order-number`
- A newer API (e.g. Wallet for Digital) has both `google-order-number` **and** `merchant-order-number`

  ```
  <google-order-number>542579893702676</google-order-number>
  <merchant-order-number>GWDG_S.D.2063320223607852</merchant-order-number>
  ```

While you do get the `merchant-order-number` in the API you are using, I don't believe you can "tie" it to `google-order-number` for the purposes of querying it via `Notification History API` (unless it's a "general" query - like time period for example, <strike>or perhaps **after** you receive `new-order-notification` which contains both</strike> - Oops, actually don't think you get this because again, this is a "legacy" Google Checkout API - re: Notification API).

Hth....